# Get a list of computers that are mapped to a server

Tags: powershell, script, network-shares, cmd.exe

Is there a way to get a list of all computers that are mapped to a network file share server? Each one may have a different driver letter, but the server name would be the same.

Scenario: Provide a list of any computer with a drive mapping to \CompanyFileShare\c$

I'm open to using existing software, or trying to come up with a script.

Answer (score 4):

On the server, open Computer Management and navigate to System Tools -> Shared Folders.

- The Shares folder will list the # of Client Connections for each share.
- The Sessions folder will list each client connection to any share.
- The Open Files folder will list currently locked files by filename and user (but not client computer).

You cannot view a list of client connections per share.

Note: From there, you can export the list by right clicking and clicking Export List.

Answer (score 2):

I found something similar to your question from this blog: [Determine which drives are map to network shares](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/10/27/how-can-i-determine-which-drives-are-mapped-to-network-shares/), they have given a script and somehow you can edit it to your needs. Take a good read.

> And so it’s Win32_LogicalDisk to the rescue. With this class not only
>   can we determine which drives are mapped to network shares, but we can
>   also determine which network shares they map to. And to do that
>   requires nothing more than a script like this:
>
> ```
> strComputer = “.”
> Set objWMIService = GetObject(“winmgmts:\\” & strComputer & “\root\cimv2”)
>
> Set colDrives = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
>     (“Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4”)
>
> For Each objDrive in colDrives
>     Wscript.Echo “Drive letter: ” & objDrive.DeviceID
>     Wscript.Echo “Network path: ” & objDrive.ProviderName
>
> Next
> ```
>
> The script starts out by connecting to the WMI service on the local
>   computer. (As usual, you can modify this script to run against a
>   remote computer simply by assigning the name of that machine to the
>   variable strComputer.) We then use this line of code to return a
>   collection of all the mapped network drives:
>
> ```
> Set colDrives = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
>
> (“Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4”)
> ```
>
> The key here – as you might have guessed – lies in our Where clause.
>   We’re asking for all instances of the class where the DriveType is
>   equal to 4; needless to say, a DriveType equal to 4 represents a
>   mapped network drive. (For other DriveType values, see the WMI SDK on
>   MSDN.) The query returns a collection of all the mapped drives; we
>   then set up a For Each loop to walk through that collection. For each
>   mapped drive we echo the value of two properties: DeviceID, which
>   returns the drive letter for the drive; and ProviderName, which
>   returns the network share the drive is mapped to.
>
> In other words, we get back information similar to this:
>
> ```
> Drive letter: E:
>
> Network path: \\atl-fs-01\public
>
> Drive letter: F:
>
> Network path: \\atl-fs-01\finance
>
> Drive letter: G:
>
> Network path: \\atl-fs-01\users\kenmyer
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up leveraging a tool we have in house called Lansweeper. I wasn't aware of its capabilities as first, but it has a lot of information on our assets including mapped network drives. I was able to run a report on all of our 3000+ assets in moments and I got exactly what I needed. Thank you for your help.